# How will I permanently delete my coc account in my new Apple account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have linked my CoC to my new device, but even though I have changed my Apple account and logged in the new account on the device, I can't over write it.

Comment: Change Game Center account. Remove CoC and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset your device to factory settings, that way all your apps, accounts and preferred settings will be deleted. Then you can install clash of clans and it will give you a fresh account. That is the only way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Check Game Center account login credentials. Use different Game center credentials  to login to CoC.